# SQL Join Question

Tags: sql, select, join, count

I have 2 tables like this :

category_table:

```
data_id  cat_id
      1       1
      1       2
      3       1
      3       3
      4       5
      4       6
```

data_table:

```
data_id  example_data
      1             x
      2             y
      3             m
      4             i
```

what I need is to count number of data_table records that are grouped with category 1 **AND** 2

Comment: you should ideally post what you've attempted.  this is not a do my work for me site.

Comment: DO you mean _records with category 1 AND 2_ (ie only data_id 1) or _records with category 1_ AND _records with category 2_ (ie data_id 1 and data_id 3)? It's slightly unclear from your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: After re-reading your question, is this what you're looking for? A count of elements from data_table where there exists an entry in the category_table for both categories 1 and 2?

```
select
    count(*)
from
    data_table d
    inner join category_table c1
        on  d.data_id = c1.data_id
    inner join category_table c2
        on  d.data_id = c2.data_id
where
    c1.cat_id = 1
    c2.cat_id = 2
```

(old answer below this...)

If you want a straight count of all records:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    data_table d
    inner join category_table c
        on  d.data_id = c.data_id
where
    c.cat_id in (1, 2)
```

If you want a count for each category:

```
select
    c.cat_id, count(*)
from
    data_table d
    inner join category_table c
        on  d.data_id = c.data_id
where
    c.cat_id in (1, 2)
group by
    c.cat_id
```

Comment: Then you'll need to post some more information in your question. Preferably with some sample data and expected results.

Comment: 'in (1, 2)' returns records with _category 1 OR 2_, not _category 1 AND 2_ ... is this what the OP wants?

Comment: thank Derek but its selecting records that grouped with cat 1 OR 2 but I need to select records that are grouped with both of them .

Comment: Right, I just re-read the question and editted my answer above. I think the revised query is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(CAT_ID) 
FROM CATEGORY_TABLE 
JOIN DATA_TABLE ON CATEGORY_TABLE.CAT_ID=DATA_TABLE.DATA_ID 
WHERE CATEGORY_TABLE.CAT_ID IN (1,2)
```

Comment: 'in (1, 2)' returns records with _category 1 OR 2_, not _category 1 AND 2_ ... is this what the OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

```
 select Cat_id,COUNT(*) [number of data_table] from data_table
 inner join category_table on category_table.data_id = data_table.data_id 
 group by Cat_id
```

OR

```
  select Cat_id,COUNT(*) [number of data_table] from category_table
  group by Cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the rows in data_table whose data_id is associated (in category_table) with a cat_id of 1 **and also with** a cat_id of 2...

```
select count(*) from data_table
where data_id in 
 (select data_id from category_table as ct1 where ct1.cat_id=1 and exists
  (select * from category_table as ct2 where ct2.cat_id=1 and ct2.data_id=ct1.data_id)
  )
```

In your case, **this will return a value of 1**, for the first row of the data_table (1 : x), since that data_id (1) is the only one with a row in category_table for which cat_id=1 and also a row for which cat_id=2.

Comment: Thanks Richard , your code and Derek's latest code both are working